# How to do in Laravel, subquery with calculated fields on SELECT?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

How can I make this query in Laravel eloquent. Please, no DB Record solution.

```
SELECT slo.batch, 
       slo.type, 
       (SELECT Count(sl1.id) 
        FROM   sync_log sl1 
        WHERE  sl1.status = 1 
               AND sl1.batch = slo.batch) AS success, 
       (SELECT Count(sl2.id) 
        FROM   sync_log sl2 
        WHERE  sl2.status = 0 
               AND sl2.batch = slo.batch) AS failed, 
       slo.created_at 
FROM   sync_log slo 
GROUP  BY batch 
ORDER  BY slo.created_at
```

Below is the database table.
[image]

Comment: I need to do this in Eloquent, not DB Record

Comment: then provide more details than a query, what are the models ? what is the relation between them ? what are you trying to count (model wise) ?

Comment: Why `type` is not in group by ? if there are different types in single batch then which type you expect to be returned?

Comment: @N69S @M Khalid Junaid Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
$result=DB::table('sync_log as slo')
    ->select('slo.batch','slo.type', 'slo.created_at', DB::raw(('SELECT Count(sl1.id) FROM sync_log sl1 WHERE sl1.status=1 AND sl1.batch = slo.batch) AS success'), DB::raw(('SELECT Count(sl2.id) FROM sync_log sl2 WHERE sl2.status = 0 AND sl2.batch = slo.batch) AS failed') 
    ->groupBy('batch')
    ->orderBy('slo.created_at')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I have done with DB record, but I need with Eloquent ORM solution

Answer (score 0):

Without any idea on your structure or models. guessing a manyToMany relation wetween batch and type where `sync_log` is the pivot table between them.

```php
$batchs = Batch::withCount([
    'types as success' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', 1);
    },
    'types as failed' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', 0);
    }])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Eloquent ORM it can be tricky but I guess will work, you can define `hasMany` relation(s) in same model which will relate to same model using `batch` attribute/key like

```
class SyncLog  extends  Model
{
 
    public function success_batches()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SyncLog::class, 'batch', 'batch')->where('status',1);
    }
    
    public function failed_batches()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SyncLog::class, 'batch', 'batch')->where('status',0);
    }
}
```

Then using your model you can get count for these relations using `withCount`

```
$bacthes = SyncLog::withCount(['success_batches','failed_batches'])
                   ->select(['batch','type'])
                   ->distinct()
                   ->orderBy('created_at')
                   ->get();
```

If you don't want to define it twice based on where clause then you can follow the approach explained in @N69S's answer like

```
class SyncLog  extends  Model
{
 
    public function batches()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SyncLog::class, 'batch', 'batch');
    }
}

$bacthes = SyncLog::withCount([
                    'batches as success' => function ($query) {
                        $query->where('status', 1);
                    },
                    'batches as failed' => function ($query) {
                        $query->where('status', 0);
                    }])
                   ->select(['batch','type'])
                   ->distinct()
                   ->orderBy('created_at')
                   ->get();
```